# Math with bigdecimal resulting in 0

Tags: java, precision

I'm trying to figure a problem out with BigDecimal. My code:

```
BigDecimal tweetcount = new BigDecimal(3344048);
BigDecimal emotionCountBig = new BigDecimal(855937);
BigDecimal emotionCountSentenceBig = new BigDecimal(84988); 

MathContext mc = new MathContext(64);
PMI[cnt] = (emotionCountSentenceBig.divide((tweetcount.multiply(emotionCountBig,mc)),RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
```

What I'd like to do is: `emotionCountSentenceBig/(emotionCountBig*tweetcount)`

(The values can be bigger)

If i try this I get a zero, which is not possible. Any help ?

Comment: I suspect what you are modelling is not accurate to more a few decimal places, let alone 16.  I suggest using `double` type instead.

Comment: Probably, but the number gotten from the multiplication is too big for a double. Is there a way around that ?

Comment: @Ojtwist I doubt it - you are probably doing an integer multiplication.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Very good point indeed. I have edited accordindly.

Comment: The maximum value for double is `179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368`
Are you sure you have using `double` and not `int`?

Comment: Hmmm I will investigate this. Because it is not that big :P

Comment: @Ojtwist I have edited my answer to use doubles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the MathContext for the division too:

```
emotionCountSentenceBig.divide(tweetcount.multiply(emotionCountBig, mc), mc);
```

That gives the expected result:

> 2.969226352632111794036880818610913852084810652372969382467557947E-8

Now as rightly commented by @PeterLawrey you could use doubles instead:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    double tweetcount = 3344048;
    double emotionCount = 855937;
    double emotionCountSentence = 84988;

    double result = emotionCountSentence / (tweetcount * emotionCount);

    System.out.println("result = " + result);
}
```

which prints:

> result = 2.9692263526321117E-8

Note that if you use:

```
double result = 84988 / (3344048 * 855937);
```

you are actually doing your operations (* and /) on integer and it will return 0. You can prevent it by explicitly using a double, for example (note the `d`):

```
double result = 84988d / (3344048d * 855937);
```

Comment: How can i get that value ? Because if I debug that, the only value I see is intCompact, which is not correct.

Comment: What is intCompact? I just copied your code with the modification I propose and printed the result in a `main` method and ran the program.

Comment: how can I add the d when the number is in a variable ?

Comment: Watch out for integer overflow on the multiply.  You just need to make one of the denominators a `double`

Answer (score 2):

I would use `double`

```
int tweetcount = 3344048;
int emotionCountBig = 855937;
int emotionCountSentenceBig = 84988;

double pmi = emotionCountSentenceBig/((double) tweetcount * emotionCountBig);
System.out.println(pmi);
```

prints

```
2.9692263526321117E-8
```

which is close to the answer using BigDecimal

```
2.969226352632111794036880818610913852084810652372969382467557947E-8
```